# Running javascript function on data from .load(url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Basically, I have a page with a "tabbed" div and when a user clicks on one of the tabs there is an .html page loaded into that div.  I was wondering is there anyway that I can have a JS function ran on that new data that is loaded from the .load() javascript function.

Here's the function that loads the new data;

```
    function switchAssetTabContent(tabContext, func, params) {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_tcAssetAllocation_tpAssetClassPrimary").html('<table width="375px" height="auto" style="min-height: 100px; height: auto; width: 260px;"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="/backoffice/Prospects/App360/images/spinwait.gif" /></td></tr></table>');
    var url = "pageFragments/overview/" + tabContext + ".html";
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_tcAssetAllocation_tpAssetClassPrimary").load( url +"?" + (new Date().getTime()), params, updateYesterday );
    }
```

the thing is that the data that is loaded is as follows;

```
<div bgcolor="white" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_pnlAssetClassAllocation">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 375px;" border="0">
    <tr><td
        valign="top"
        style="background-color: white vertical-align: top; width: 175px"
        id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_tdAssetClassChart">
        <div bgcolor="white" style="padding:0" id="AssetClassChartControlDiv" class="chart">
        </div>
        </td>
      <td valign="top">

        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_pnlAssetClassLegend">

          <input type="hidden" value="" name="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xOverview1xuwgAssetClassChartLegend" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_uwgAssetClassChartLegend" />
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xOverview1xuwgAssetClassChartLegend_main">
              <tr id="ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xOverview1xuwgAssetClassChartLegend_mr">
                <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div id="AssetClassChartControl_legend" class="legend">
                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>

        </div>

</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

and i have js functions written on the main page that calls that info that uses the ID's of those now loaded html `<div>`s and `<span>`s.  Can i just put the .js functions on the included page?  I just thought i should only include my js functions in the `<head></head>` or outside of the `<body></body>` tags.....
any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're already calling the function `updateYesterday` when the load request is complete.

Comment: Your `.load()` is overwriting the table that was added just before it, are you sure you're loading into the correct place?

Comment: @Barmar: That table's only content is a `<img src="…/spinwait.gif" />`, so probably yes.

Comment: @bfavaretto that is just to append to the url of what is being loaded, do you think that is what is causing my data to now show?  I'm only confused because when i just add the HTML of the page called by .load() function onto the site it renders the data perfectly, but when used in confuction with the .load() function via JS nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Barmar, that is just supposed to be a spinning icon saying something is being loaded is all, it gives the user something to show them the data is being rendered

Comment: If the HTML being loaded contains any inline Javascript, `load()` will evaluate it after inserting the HTML.

Comment: @barmar there isn't any inline javascript in it, the function calls are in the document.ready(){} function of the page, but since the function that calls the .load() of the new html is done after the document.ready() has completed it does not work correctly.  Is there some sort of inline code i can use the doesn't have to be an onclick event or something in the <div> provided above that would re-run the document.ready() function?  I'm not javascript guy as you can tell so sorry if these should be easily known

Comment: If you want to run a function after the new HTML is loaded, that's what the third argument to `.load()` is for. You're already using that to call `updateYesterday()`. Replace that with a function that calls `updateYesterday()` and whatever else you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-run your `document.ready()` function, you can make it a named function:

```
function myReadyFunction() { ... }

document.ready(myReadyFunction);
```

Then you can use it when calling `.load()`:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_tcAssetAllocation_tpAssetClassPrimary").load( url +"?" + (new Date().getTime()), params, myReadyFunction );
```